# Aerospike session: Store some data in separate bin

Tags: aerospike, express-session

At the time of saving the session, `[aerospike express session store][1]` stringifies the object and saves it in one bin (named session). I want to save some of the data in separate bin so that I can create a secondary index on them? Any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unfortunately not possible at the moment. But maybe we can work out a solution via the [Github issue](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-session-store-expressjs/issues/7) you filed for the `aerospike-session-store` module.